# App crashes and doesn't store data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason my app crashes after completing registration when its supposed to take you to the main activity. It's also supposed to store data in a Firestore database but for some reason it doesn't. I hope someone of you coding geniuses can help me and please don't judge me, I'm a beginner.
Here is the code:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText mName, mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mRegister, mContinue;
    TextView mLoginText;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar2;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userID;
    com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker mCcp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mRegister = findViewById(R.id.register);
        mLoginText = findViewById(R.id.loginText);
        mContinue = findViewById(R.id.continueBtn);
        mCcp = findViewById(R.id.ccp);

        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mProgressBar2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);


        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String fullName = mName.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required!");
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                }
                if(password.length() < 6){
                    mPassword.setError("Password must be at least 6 characters long!");
                }

                mLoginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mCcp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mProgressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Register the user in firebase

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){


                            // send verification
                            FirebaseUser fuser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            fuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Verification email has been sent. Please check your mail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"OnFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            });




                            fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                            Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("fName",fullName);
                            user.put("eMail",email);
                            user.put("Country",mCcp);
                            documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener) (aVoid) -> {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: User profile is registered for " + userID);
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            });
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registering was successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });



        mLoginText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            }
        });

        mContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){
                mEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mContinue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCcp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Hope you can help me!

Ok here is the error:

```
2020-07-26 13:20:55.816 5024-5024/noor.kaspar.lessonary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: noor.kaspar.lessonary, PID: 5024
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker (found in field Country)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.UserData$ParseContext.createError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:293)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:405)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:254)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseMap(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:274)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:230)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseSetData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:75)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:172)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:152)
        at noor.kaspar.lessonary.Register$1$1.onComplete(Register.java:114)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The way I understand is that I can't use

```
com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker mCcp;
```

Well, how else am I supposed to store the country in database.
Here is the activity_register.xml code for the country picker:

```
   <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        android:id="@+id/ccp"
        android:layout_width="349dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:ccp_showFullName="true"
        app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
        app:ccp_showPhoneCode="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />
```

And I need to store that in the firestore document, so if I can't use that, how else am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save Country as string and take country form   mCcp by below code.
firestore can't save object it save only known data types data like int, string ,boolean

So, please change your code  user.put("Country",mCcp); to user.put("Country",mCcp, getDefaultCountryName());

Comment: Thanks this solved the inital problem but now I am facing a weird situation: even after selecting a different country from the dropdown, it registers it as "India" in the Firestore database. Can you help me and if so do you need any additional details?

Comment: use mCcp.getSelectedCountryName() inlace of mCcp.getDefaultCountryName()

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to extract `Country Code` from `CountryCodePicker`

```
user.put("Country",mCcp.getSelectedCountryName());
```

Edit: This is the code to @VishalSojitra's answer

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Thanks this solved the inital problem but now I am facing a weird situation: even after selecting a different country from the dropdown, it registers it as "India" in the Firestore database. Can you help me and if so do you need any additional details?

Comment: Ok it's fixed now.